# java: Class.Load?

Tags: java, class, load

I'm fairly confused about the **Class.forName** in java. how do we explain what **Class.forName** is from a C# perspective?

use case: **java.lang.Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");**

Comment: Do you mean java.lang.Class.forName(...)

Comment: @sbridges yes sry i've updated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class.forName returns an instance of a Class object.  Class is equivalent to the c# class object.

Class.forName forces classes to load, if they have not already been loaded.  As part of the class loading process is invoking any static blocks defined in the class.  A static block looks like,

```
class Foo {
    static {
         System.out.println("loaded Foo");
    }
}

//running this will print "loaded Foo"
Class.forName("Foo");
```

Static blocks are invoked only once, the first time a class is loaded, so repeatedly calling Class.forName("Foo") will only cause "loaded Foo" to be printed once.  Creating a new instance of Foo will also cause the class to be loaded, if it has not already been loaded.

Generally, JDBC drivers will register themselves by calling [DriverManager.registerDriver()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#registerDriver%28java.sql.Driver%29) in a static block, which is why calling Class.forName() loads the driver.

Comment: in c# static constructors can be called automatically when "the first instance of the class is created or when any static member is called". Can we achieve this too with java? (abit like implicit calling Class.forName)

Comment: The static block will be invoked whenever the class is first loaded.  Creating an instance of Foo would also cause the static block to be invoked.  Edited my answer to be clearer about this.

Comment: Hey thx for the help. btw is Class.forName thread safe? (as in will it ensure 100% that the code within the static block will be run only once at most?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.lang.Class.forName, when you want to instantiate an object in Java by simply giving objects name as a String.

Its similar to using Activator.CreateInstance(objectType) in c#.

For more info, read http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d49ss92b(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: except that Class.forName does not instantiate an object of the class.